# How to interpret Apple Core Media Frame Quanta numbers?

Tags: macos, video-capture, core-media

The Apple Mac OS framework offers an api [called `CMTimeCodeFormatDescriptionGetFrameQuanta`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489418-cmtimecodeformatdescriptiongetfr)

I'm trying to use this in a Swift Mac program's user interface as part of a pick list of video formats available from webcams and other video sources. It returns an integer. The  [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489418-cmtimecodeformatdescriptiongetfr) says this about the units of its result.

> Returns the frames/sec for timecode (e.g. 30) OR frames/tick for counter mode.

How do I make sense of *frames/tick*? The built in iSight camera gives back `0`, `1932`, or `35632`, depending on the resolution of the format. A Logitec USB cam gives back mostly `73600`, but sometimes `0` or `1932`, also depending on resolution.

What does this number mean? How can I render it in a way that makes sense to end users, like *30fps* or *24fps*?

Comment: I know nothing about the domain, but did you see this method:  CMTimeCodeFormatDescriptionGetFrameDuration  [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489815-cmtimecodeformatdescriptiongetfr?language=objc]. The description says "Returns the duration of each frame (e.g. 100/2997)", where e.g. 2997 / 100 = 29.97fps

Comment: I did see that. I will take a closer look.